# Why is everything scrolling along with the table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just had a question answered that solved almost everything: I have three parts that I wanted to edit separately, and now when i put the other two parts back in, they are included within my table section and scroll with the table rather than being stuck underneath the table.

The page should look like this:

-Header (APP Single Page App)

-Table of Users

-Page number and pagination

-Edit User -New User, next to each other in two columns. I can't find or not sure how to research this specific type of question.

MY CSS:

```
.my-custom-scrollbar {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.table-wrapper-scroll-y {
  display: block;
}

th {
  background: #67c8f5;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.table {
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="myScript.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Users</title>
        <meta name="description" content="APP Web Task 5">
        <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">
    </head>
<!--Text body-->
<body>
  <!--header-->

  <header class="container jumbotron text-center">
    <h2>APP Single Page App</h2>
  </header>

  <!--Section 1, table-->
  <div class="container">
    <section id="sectUsers">
      <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
        <table id="tblUsers" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed">
          <!--Table header-->
          <thead class="table table-bordered table-primary table-striped text-center">
            <tr id="tblUserHeader">
              <th scope="col">User ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Avatar</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <!--Table body-->
          <tbody class="table table-bordered">
            <tr id="user1">
              <td scope="row"><b>1</b></td>
              <td>george.bluth@reqres.in</td>
              <td>George</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Bluth</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user2">
              <td scope="row"><b>2</b></td>
              <td>janet.weaver@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Janet</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Weaver</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user3">
              <td scope="row"><b>3</b></td>
              <td>emma.wong@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Emma</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Wong</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>


            <tr id="user4">
              <td scope="row"><b>4</b></td>
              <td>eve.holt@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Eve</td>
              <td class="w3-center">Holt</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user5">
              <td scope="row"><b>5</b></td>
              <td>charles.morris@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Charles</td>
              <td>Morris</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="user6">
              <td scope="row"><b>6</b></td>
              <td>tracey.ramos@reqres.in</td>
              <td>Tracey</td>
              <td>Ramos</td>
              <td>
                <div><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg" alt="avatar" class="rounded-circle"></div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
      </div>
    </section>

    <nav aria-label="...">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item disabled">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item active">
          <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>


<!--Section two, Edit User-->
            <section id="sectUser" >
                <div >
                    <h2 >User</h2>
                    <div >
                        <img id="userAvatar" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg" alt="avatar">
                        <form id="frmUser" >
                            <label>User ID:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="userID">
                            <br>
                            <label>Email:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="userEmail">
                            <br>
                            <label>First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="userFirstName">
                            <br>
                            <label>Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="userLastName">
                            <div >
                                <button id="btnSaveUser" >Save Changes</button>
                                <button id="btnDeleteUser" >Delete User</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

<!--Section three, Add new user-->
            <section id="sectNewUser" >
                <div >
                    <h2 >New User</h2>
                    <div >
                        <form id="frmNewUser" >
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="userName">
                            <br>
                            <label>Job:</label>
                            <input type="text" id="userJob">
                            <br>
                            <div >
                                <button id="btnNewUser" >New User</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: close the table tag under </tbody>

Comment: You have no `</table` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the tag `</table>`.